# Can I place "parent theme" inside a child theme folder?

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

Client has a very strange request where they want to just install Child theme and have the parent theme be inside child theme.

So essentially, they don't want to show parent theme in the list of Available or installed themes in WP theme section.

Wondering if this is even possible? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is New Idea, but till now there is no way we can install parent theme inside child theme, but according to your requirement we can hide the theme from the list of available themes.

this approach is not global but your project-specific
you can identify your theme name which you want to hide.
and then using CSS you can hide it

for example: here I attached 2 pic

[image: available themes]

in this i have prent theme Divi which i hide it using css data selector

```
[data-slug="Divi"] {     display: none; }
```

[image: hide parent theme]

As I am not front-end developer, hiding like this cause design issue so you can improve this.
Thank you